# How to recover or change Oracle sysdba password

Tags: linux, oracle, authentication, passwords, sysdba

We are working with an oracle database in which the person that set it up is "long gone" and thus do not know the sysdba password, but need it. We have root access to the box (its on linux). Is there any way to recover or change the sys passwords?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried logging into Linux as your installed Oracle user then

```
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
```

When you log in you'll be able to change your password.

```
alter user sys identified by <new password>;
```

Good luck :)

Comment: an addition... if you have root access but not the oracle user, login as root then "su - oracle" and follow Paul's instructions. Also try all the default oracle passwords. Last option is to look at OUTLN and DBSNMP accounts and Oracle hacks around that.

Comment: It helped me, the default passwords in oracle 11g didn't work out. Does this mean that oracle can be compromised easily.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to the database locally using the combination of environment variables:

- **ORACLE_HOME**
- **ORACLE_SID** .

Depending on your **OS**:

**Unix/Linux:**

```
export ORACLE_HOME=<oracle_home_directory_till_db_home>
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=<your_oracle_sid>
SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA
```

**Windows**

```
set ORACLE_HOME=<oracle_home_path_till_db_home>
set PATH=%PATH%||%ORACLE_HOME%\bin
set ORACLE_SID=<your_oracle_sid>
SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA
```

Once connected, you could then **alter the user** to **modify the password**:

```
ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY password;
```

Comment: Depending on your server settings, you may also have to update your sqlnet.ora SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS) in order to run SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA