# Determing the ORACLE root

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I recently installed Oracle Express Edition 10g on my Ubuntu from apt-get. My problem is I dont know exactly in which directory the Oracle resides. I want to set ORACLE_HOME to the path where Oracle has been installed, so that i can create database from terminal. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Not programming related. Voting to migrate to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg -L oracle-xe
```

Will list all the files installed by the oracle-xe package. From that, you should be able to figure out a suitable value for ORACLE_BASE and ORACLE_HOME.

It's possible that the installation has scattered the files around the filesystem, following the usual pattern for Unix applications (eg executables in /usr/bin, libraries in /usr/lib, data in /var/lib/oracle-xe). In that case, there might not be a sensible value for ORACLE_HOME.

According to answers to a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747462/how-to-correctly-set-the-oracle-home-variable-on-ubuntu-9-x), it seems that the important thing is that ORACLE_HOME points to the location where your static files (code, libraries, and resources) are installed. Something like:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server
```

I'm not sure how Oracle then knows where to create the database. Hopefully it doesn't just put it in the ORACLE_HOME, because that's in /usr, which should be read-only.

Comment: Thanks for help. My installation is scattered around the filesystem. Any idea where I can set my ORACLE_HOME value?

Comment: Have a look at the other question i've posted a link to, and see if that helps. If it does, consider closing your question as a duplicate of that question - can you do that?