# Unable to log-in using PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have problem with logging into my database using Pl/SQL Developer. All connection parameters are defined in TNSNAMES.ORA and work perfectly with SQL Developer.

Unfortunately, when I try to connect using PL/SQL Developer, I am receiving a message with no content. I am using version 9.0.6.1665.

Is this a known issue and what might I be doing wrong?

Here is image of this strange error:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the error and _how_ you are attempting to connect with PL/SQL Developer. Otherwise people are just going to be guessing. I also can't remember if it uses ODBC..? I think it might do, in which case do you have that set up correctly? You won't be able to post an actual screenshot but you can comment with a link.

Comment: If you have more than one Oracle Home, make sure the right one is selected (in tools->preferences)

Comment: I think it can use ODBC (but I'm not 100% sure). How can I check, if it really does?

Comment: By default it will use the OCI libraries of your Oracle Home installation. I'm not sure if it can use ODBC.

Comment: You may want to look at the PL/SQL Developer forums.  I found a [few](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=44474#Post44474) [threads](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=44827&Searchpage=2&Main=11700&Words=login+empty+error&Search=true#Post44827) that suggest the problem may be caused by running a 10g client on Windows 7.  Apparently only Only 11g clients are supported on Windows 7.

Comment: I asked Pl/Sql Support for help, if something interesting come out I will post here. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you don't have an ORACLE CLIENT installed, which is required. SQL Developer connects (by default) using JDBC (and does not require an Oracle Client). I don't know who is up-voting the "might be ODBC" related comments. There is no ODBC anything involved with PLD. Period.

Comment: are you installed it in "Program Files (x86)" folder?

Answer (score 7):

Probably you might have already resolved your issue, but I would like to add my solution here.

I faced the same issue of blank error screen on trying to logon to PL/SQL Developer.
OS Win 7
Pl/SQL Dev 7.1.3
Oracle client 10g

Step 1: I checked the output of "tnsping". It resulted in error - Message 3511 not found
The cause was incorrect setting of ORACLE_HOME value in my environment.
After correcting ORACLE_HOME, tnsping started to work but I still got the same blank error screen in PL/SQL Developer. 
**Edit:** Refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747462/how-to-correctly-set-the-oracle-home-variable-on-ubuntu-9-x) for more info on setting ORACLE_HOME correctly.

Step 2: I started PL/SQL Developer with option "Run as Administrator". After providing the administrator password, I was able to logon successfully through PL/SQL Developer

Step 3: Later I changed the User Account Control settings (Win 7 Control Panel > User Accounts > Change User Account Control settings). I set it to "Never notify" and restarted my PC. Thereafter, I ran PL/SQL Developer as normal user and did not face the issue.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I had wrong ORACLE_HOME. Removing it from Environment variables helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you are connected to Network/VPN.
2. Open PL/SQL Developer.
3. Click on Tools -> Preferences. Select the very first option: Connection.
4. From Oracle Home drop down list, select the correct option. If you are not sure which is correct, try choosing one after another until the one that works for you.
5. Restart PL/SQL Developer.
6. Cross your fingers and retry to connect to your databases. If it works, say "Buiya". If it doesn't, scream "F***", and Google search.

Answer (score 0):

> **5 Things to get PLSQL Developer to work after its installation.**

1. You need an Oracle Client. Google ***"Oracle Tech Support Download"*** and  download a suitable Oracle Client for your environment(w32/64 or linux). When you install, make sure your picks includes "runtime" option. Get the newest appropriate version even if your PL/SQL Developer is old. Mine is

   - "win32_11gR2_client".
2. Use your Control Panel's **System Settings**, edit your environmental vars - make sure Oracle's bin **path** is in both System Path and User Path or at least User Path. Mine is

   - C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
3. Re-install your PL/SQL Developer if you still have login issue. The developer will open up a blank doc in which you can use HELP's "Register" item to **register your Product-Key and your (given serial No. and password)**.
4. Check "Support Info" under HELP. Go thru their info. Edit your environmental var to make sure the info gets all the correct search paths. Use the **Tools/Preferences/Connection/(Oracle Home and OCI library) Dropdown** to select the desired version
   [image: Picture--See your options in Registry]
5. Go to Oracle Top Directory.  Use search function to search all the subdirectories for a file called **tnsnames.ora**.

   a.  Enter that path to System setting's Environment.

   b.  Follow the expected format, provide the names for TNS resolution. Edit the file to include an addr list

   var1 =
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = _____)(PORT = ____))
   (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = _____)))

   var2 = 
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ______)(PORT = ____))
   (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = _____)))

SERVICE_NAME and SID are interchangeable!