# Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus in UNIX

Tags: sqlplus

I am getting the belwo mentioned error while trying to open sqlplus from UNIX server.

Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
Message file sp1.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correctly set the ORACLE\_HOME variable on Ubuntu 9.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747462/how-to-correctly-set-the-oracle-home-variable-on-ubuntu-9-x)